# Yii2 - Wrong homeUrl when setting baseUrl in urlManager

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, yii2

I have a site is in a "web" subfolder, that is hidden with .htaccess so that people accessing http://www.example.com gets served with http://www.example.com/web/index.php .

To set this behaviour and prevent Yii2 from generating links with the "web" folder, I have set "baseUrl" to "/" in the urlManager.

Now all the pages are served right, and all the links are created correctly, but the Yii::$app->homeUrl variable has an incorrect value "**//**" when it should be "**/**", so it creates problems with login/logout.

If i remove the baseUrl it works correctly, but adding the "web" parent folder to all urls.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have set baseUrl to an empty string, and it fixed this problem, but it doesn't have sense for me. Can someone explain me what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Had same trouble. I just added `'homeUrl' => '/'` option to config root.